# Beautifulsoup and scraping page with limited class elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this page located here: http://sagarin.com/sports/cfsend.htm

The information that I need is only the team name and the Rating applied to each team.  However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to extract that data since the page has very basic HTML tagging.  The entire table (if you can really call it that) appears to be within a set of `font` tag with the color of black (#000000).

It does appear that every team name I need is enclosed in `<font>` tags with the color #000000 applied to the team name while every rating is inside another `<font>` tag with the color #9900ff.  It also appears that there are 4 useless `<font>` tags between the every relevant two  tags that I need.  Any idea on how to extract these two specific fonts tags?

Comment: The most convenient library would be lxml. Do you have it installed?

Comment: Or beautifulsoup (bs4)

Answer (score 0):

So I've played around with it for a bit and have some basic code:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.usatoday.com/sports/ncaaf/sagarin/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
page_source = soup.find("font", {"color": "#000000"})

temp_list = page_source.find_all("font", {"color": "#000000"})
for teams in temp_list[2:-3:2]:
    print(teams.text)
```

This gets me the a list of team names but I still need to strip out quite a bit of crap out of it.  It's a start at least for just a poorly designed web page.